# Likelihood for a weighted sum of Poisson distributions with Dirichlet prior for weights

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, likelihood

Lets assume I have a sample $X_1, X_1, ..., X_n$, a random variable $H \sim  Dirichlet(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and we have that

$X_i | H = (h_1, h_2) \sim Pois( h_1 \cdot \lambda_1 + h_2 \cdot \lambda_2)$, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 >0$.

Then the likelihood for my sample $X_1, X_1, ..., X_n$ is:

$$
\prod \limits_{i=1}^n P(X_i = x_i) = Dirichlet(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)  \prod \limits_{i=1}^n Pois( h_1 \cdot \lambda_1 + h_2 \cdot \lambda_2) = 
$$
$$
=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1) \Gamma(\alpha_2)} h_1^{\alpha_1 -1 }h_2^{\alpha_1 -1 } \prod \limits_{i=1}^n Pois( h_1 \cdot \lambda_1 + h_2 \cdot \lambda_2)
$$

Am I right?
I would be very grateful for evaluating, whether this is correct.

Comment: The label "Dirichlet" for the r.v. $H$ could be changed to "Beta", as $h_2 = 1 - h_1$ by necessity; the parameter for the Poisson can be rewritten as $\lambda_2 + h(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)$, for example.  Also, this is not a mixture model as written; do you want a mixture of Poissons or just the mean parameter to be randomly selected before sampling begins, which is what you have now?

Comment: Oh, yeah you are right. It's rather a weighted sum. I meant a weighted sum. Thank you very much for your remarks!

Comment: I want the parameter to be randomly selected.